# MYSQL - Querying a table with optional filters and default value

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks like this:

| ID | KEY | FILTER_NAME | FILTER_VALUE | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | country | USA | value1 |
| 2 | a | inRockBand | true | value2 |
| 3 | a |  |  | value3 |
| 4 | b | city | MADRID | value4 |
| 5 | b | isLawer | true | value5 |
| 6 | b |  |  | value6 |

I would like to create a query that can receive generic filter (optional) parameters and fetches a single row **per key** accordingly (when optional filters don't match - the query will return the row with null filter name\value as these are the default rows)

for example:

```
select * from table where filterName = 'country' and filter_value = 'SPAIN'
```

will return:

| ID | KEY | FILTER_NAME | FILTER_VALUE | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | a |  |  | value3 |
| 6 | b |  |  | value6 |

while

```
select * from table where filterName = 'inRockBand' and filter_value = 'true'
```

will return:

| ID | KEY | FILTER_NAME | FILTER_VALUE | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | a | inRockBand | true | value2 |
| 6 | b |  |  | value6 |

if several filters matches several keys we should take any one key

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(t1.ID, t2.ID) ID,
       t0.`KEY`,
       COALESCE(t1.FILTER_NAME, t2.FILTER_NAME) FILTER_NAME,
       COALESCE(t1.FILTER_VALUE, t2.FILTER_VALUE) FILTER_VALUE,
       COALESCE(t1.VALUE, t2.VALUE) VALUE
FROM ( SELECT @filterName FILTER_NAME,
              @filter_value FILTER_VALUE ) criteria
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT `KEY`
             FROM test ) t0
LEFT JOIN test t1 ON criteria.FILTER_NAME = t1.FILTER_NAME
                 AND criteria.FILTER_VALUE = t1.FILTER_VALUE
                 AND t0.`key` = t1.`key`
LEFT JOIN test t2 ON '' = t2.FILTER_NAME
                 AND '' = t2.FILTER_VALUE
                 AND t0.`key` = t2.`key`
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=feceb7a404ddd6a78324664c51c3c310

Answer (score 0):

The query I used looks like so:

```sql
select * from tbl where id in(
 select min(id) 
 from (
  SELECT * 
  FROM tbl 
  where (filterName = 'inRockBand' and filterValue = 'true') 
     or filterName is null
 ) a 
 group by keyId
);
```

Comment: Is this your answer ?